# Debug STM32 with Nucleo

Tags: stm32, bootloader, programmer

Would it be possible to debug/program another PCB including an STM32 MCU with the debug connector provide on the Nucleo-G474RE? (I don't have an external programmer yet)

What would you recommend for future designs. add a JTAG connector on the PCB and always flash the STM via the JTAG or create a bootloader and do it over USB?
I guess if I want to want to flash a bootloader in the STM, I will need the JTAG connector anyway, so the USB connector will only cost me space on the PCB. Or is there another way to load a bootloader?

Comment: yes you can use the debug end of a nucleo board for other boards even for other chip vendors.  I would not say there is a 100% expectation of success, but it is well above zero.  I have used them on breakout boards for various other chis including other brands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The board manual says it is used to connect an external debugging tool to debug the target MCU on the Nucleo board. However, I see no reason why the onboard ST-LINK debugger cannot be used to debug another target (as I have done this on another Nucleo board), but the on-board target needs to be disconnected from the ST-LINK debugger pins (physically, or loading a firmware that disables the target debugging port).

You don't need to create or load a bootloader. The STM32G474RE already has a non-erasable factory bootloader that allows user firmware to be loaded over USART, I2C, SPI, and USB interfaces. If you want to program a custom bootloader you can load it via the factory bootloader. You only need the JTAG connector if you want to debug or load firmware via JTAG. And I see no reason to not wanting to debug via JTAG, except when product is ready so final version can omit JTAG.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the JP6 and JP8 jumpers on my Nucleo-G474RE, I am able to connect the embedded ST-LINK to another target through the DEBUG-connector.